# Unauthorized access to storage's table using API Management

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-api-management, azure-managed-identity

I configured MSI to table storage in my API Management:

[image]

Then, in `inboud` policy i am setting mocked url to table storage:

```
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="https://<storage>.table.core.windows.net/<table>()?$top=10" />
        <authentication-managed-identity resource="https://storage.azure.com/" />
    </inbound>
```

And i see, that token is obtained correctly:

[image]

And i am getting `403` response as follows:

```
{
    "response": {
        "status": {
            "code": 403,
            "reason": "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature."
        },
```

My question is, how to call `table` storage from `Api Management` using `managed identity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to inbound policy:

```
<set-header name="x-ms-version" exists-action="override">
    <value>@{string version = "2017-11-09"; return version;}</value>
</set-header>
```